# Do I need to create my own InvalidArgumentException.. I couldn't find any builtin type in c#

Tags: c#, exception

Do I need to create my own InvalidArgumentException.. I couldn't find any built-in types in c#... Is there any library which defines commonly used Exception classes.. Thanks

Comment: Try [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx). It's already part of .NET.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's called [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) and it's in the built-in System namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Besides `ArgumentException` there are also `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Short summary;

- `System.ArgumentException` - general exception,
- `System.ArgumentNullException` - unexpected null value,
- `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` - unexpected value.

Standard usage:

```
void GetEntity(string currentName)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentName))
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(currentName));
  }

  //...
}
```

PS.
`NotSupportedException` also comes in handy (e.g. when the set of arguments would force the method to perform not supported scenario).